# Explaining constructor and copy constructor example

Tags: c++

I have this code and I can understand what happening with the contractor of class Fat.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Block{ 
  int data;
public:
  Block(int i = 10) : data(i){ 
    cout << "I just created a Block " << endl; 
  }
  ~Block() {
    cout << "I will destroy a Block with " << data << endl; 
  }
  void inc() { 
    data++; 
  } 
};

class A{ 
  Block& block1; 
  Block block2;
  public:
    A(Block& blk) : block1(blk), block2(blk) { 
      cout << "I just created an A " << endl; 
    }

    A(const A& a): block1(a.block1), block2(a.block2) {
      cout << "I just created an A by copying but I will also do bad things" << endl;
      block1.inc(); block2.inc(); 
    }
    ~A() { 
      cout << "I will destroy an A " << endl; 
    }

    void inc() { 
      block1.inc(); block2.inc(); 
    } 
  };

class Fat{ 
  A  a; 
  A& ra; 
  A*  pa;
public:
  Fat(A& da) : a(da),ra(da) { 
    pa = new A(da);
    cout << "Fat just created !" << endl;
  }
  ~Fat() {  
    delete pa;
    cout << "Fat to be destroyed !" << endl; 
  }
    void inc() { 
      a.inc(); 
      ra.inc(); 
      pa->inc(); 
    }
  };

int main(){ 
  Block block;
  A a(block); 
  Fat fat(a);
  fat.inc();
  return 0; 
}
```

and the result of this :

```
I just created a Block 
I just created an A 
I just created an A by copying but I will also do bad things
I just created an A by copying but I will also do bad things
Fat just created !
I will destroy an A 
I will destroy a Block with 12
Fat to be destroyed !
I will destroy an A 
I will destroy a Block with 12
I will destroy an A 
I will destroy a Block with 11
I will destroy a Block with 15
```

Why does the copy constructor run twice?

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: Did you run your code into a minifier or something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question lacks every bit of effort.

Comment: Please, don't waste all that space. Put your entire code on a single line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `"I just created an A by copying but I will also do bad things"`comes from this line:

```
Fat(A& da) : a(da), ra(da) {
```

`a(da)` this one calls A's copy constructor

the seconds one from the constructer of class fat:

```
Fat(A& da) : a(da), ra(da) {
    pa = new A(da); //HERE!!
    cout << "Fat just created !" << endl;
}
```

again, with `pa = new A(da);` you call A's copy constructor.

edit: thank you for formatting your code

Comment: well it's a reference to a.

Answer (score 0):

The first copy is made to initialise the `a` member variable in `Fat`:

```
Fat(A& da) : a(da), ra(da) {
```

Then the line

```
pa = new A(da);
```

creates a new instance of `A` on the free store by copying `da` hence it calls the copy constructor. If instead you wanted to make a pointer to an existing instance of `A` you should write

```
pa = &da;
```

Comment: There is no mention of *"heap"* in C++. You are referring to the *freestore*.

Comment: @IInspectable Bjarne Stroustrup uses the term on page 277 of his book "The C++ Programming Language". It is listed as a synonym for the "free store" along with "dynamic memory". If it is good enough for Bjarne...

Comment: @IInspectable Honestly that is a very pedantic distinction and afaik most C++ committee members use the term heap so...

Comment: @Borgleader: The heap is an implementation detail, that is not mandated by the C++ standard. An implementation can choose to implement the freestore any way it sees fit. If you don't care about getting the terminology right, move on, there's nothing to be seen. It's a bit unnerving to read comments along the lines of *"Yeah, it is wrong. We know, but we don't really care, because others get it wrong, too..."*.

Comment: The heap is not "not mandated" by the C++ standard. There are only three things not mandated by the C++ standard (https://www.google.com/#q=mandate+site%3Aeel.is), and all of them are exceptions. Also, the standard does not make use of the term "freestore" (https://www.google.com/#q="freestore"+site%3Aeel.is). This message is approved by me, someone who cares about getting the terminology right.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Great, so it's called *"free store"*. About the *"not 'not mandated'"* madness, I take it you always enter a bank with the words: *"Everybody stay calm, I'm not going to rob this bank!"* Seriously, some things are implied without being explicitly spelled out.

Comment: Yes, they are. Such as the heap being the same thing as the free store.